# Why does openapi typescript angular generator generates code with old dependency versions?

Tags: angular, maven, npm, openapi, openapi-generator

I generate an openapi client for angular 8 with the following maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
  <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/../server/openapi.json</inputSpec>
        <generatorName>typescript-angular</generatorName>
        <output>${project.basedir}</output>
        <configOptions>
          <npmName>clientRest</npmName>
          <npmRepository>https://localhost:8444/repository/npm-releases/</npmRepository>
          <providedInRoot>true</providedInRoot>
          <apiModulePrefix>my</apiModulePrefix>
          <stringEnums>true</stringEnums>
          <npmVersion>1.0.2</npmVersion>
        </configOptions>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I now use this within my angular project, I always got:

> npm WARN clientRest@1.0.2 requires a peer of core-js@^2.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

But I have `core-js@3.6.0` already as dependency installed.

So my question is, what could I do against this version problem?

Comment: `3.6.0` doesn't meet `^2.4.0`

Comment: Thats clear, but is there a kind of workaround to make the generated code work? Or is only a bug report to the openapi generator project possible?